# Password Change URL in Django is accessible by directly entering URL, but fails when clicking on "Change Password" button

Tags: python, django

I am making a website based on William S. Vincent's "Django for Beginners." In the project I am building I have a homepage, with a drop-down menu that includes, among other options, a "Change Password" selection. When I go directly to the URL `127.0.0.1:8000/users/password_change/`, I arrive at the correct page, but clicking the "Change Password" option gives me the following error:

> "Using the URLconf defined in newspaper_project.urls Django tried these URL patterns in this order: 1. admin/ 2. users/signup/ [name='signup'] 3. users/login/ [name='login']...11. articles/ 12. [name='home']. The current path, users/password_change/{% url 'password_change' %}. didn't match any of these."

Below are the relevant sections of code:

```
# /Desktop/news/templates/base.html
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu"\
              data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded\
              ="false">
                {{ user.username }}
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"\
              aria-labelledby="userMenu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'article_list' %}">Entries</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'password_change'
                %}">Change password</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">
                Log Out</a>
```

```
# /Desktop/news/users/urls.py
from django.urls import path

from .views import SignUpView


urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
]
```

```
# /Desktop/news/users/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

```
# /Desktop/news/newspaper_project/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')), #new
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), #new
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')), #new 
    path('', include('pages.urls')), #new
]
```

The 'article_list' and 'logout' buttons as specified in `base.html` work, and I can access password_change by directly typing in `127.0.0.1:8000/users/password_change/`, but clicking the button gives me the error as described above. I would appreciate a solution to this issue as well as any explanation as to why this issue occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your password_change url tag is spread across two lines, so Django doesn't recognise it as a template tag. Make sure it is all in one line.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'password_change' %}">Change password</a>
```

Comment: Wow! That fixed it! Thank you so much, I never would have figured it out otherwise. Such a simple solution, but I had been struggling over it for a while. Much appreciated!